# Using jquery in js file

Tags: javascript, jquery

Okay so all I am trying to do is make the jquery work in my javascript file which is linked to a html file. I created a totally new file for this to test it. The whole contents of the html file are:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Programming\jquery-1.12.4"             type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="check.js"></script>
<head> <h1>test</h1>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

And the whole content of the js file is

```
$("h1").css("color", "red");
```

But when I open the html file in chrome the change I put in the js file with jquery doesn't show up (e.g the heading is not red). I just want to figure out how to make it so that it does.

EDIT:

Thanks for the help everybody, I was able to make it work :)

Comment: You put `H1` inside the `HEAD`? Wierd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Move your `<h1>` tag to be in the `<body>`
2. Move your `<script>` tags to the `<head>`
3. Replace your code in your JS file with what *imvain2* said, so
   that the JS will load once your document is ready.
4. Make sure you are correctly referencing your jQuery script. You can even use this to test it out:

   ```
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
   ```

Answer (score 5):

did you try this?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("h1").css("color", "red");
});
```

Answer (score 5):

not sure but, does your browser access local files directly? im pretty sure that browser sandbox gonna reject that, maybe cors plugin on chrome?

EDIT:

try importing this instead...

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to use jQuery CDN, this way you don't need to worry if jQuery loaded correctly or not.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("h1").css("color", "red");
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="check.js"></script>
<head></head>
<body>
  <h1>test</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple issue as described in other posts. All your meta, script, css references, etc. should go int the `<head>` and never header tags. Also need to correctly reference your javascript files.

```
<head> 
</head>
<body>
<header>
  <h1>test</h1>
</header>
</body>
```

Example: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bo3mwsLa/4/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use jquery in .js file all you need to do is type: src=" ..." above code.